# Color Box - External Linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

I can't seem to get my colorbox to work here, not sure whats missing. I have done this a ton of times, but apparently I am still so newb.

I have setup this sample page here:
http://www.whiterhino.us/aspire_setup/ 
(Click Either of the Red Buttons)

Wondering why the colorbox does not seem to format properly.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look at your source it appears you're missing the [`colorbox.css`](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/colorbox.css) file.

That link is to the first example from the ColorBox demos on the [website](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), but I'm pretty sure it's a standard file.

Comment: Silly Me, its waayy too late for me obviously. Nite! & Thanks!